# Cabal can't find foreign library when building on NixOS

Tags: haskell, cabal, nixos, nix

I am trying to build an internal Haskell project on NixOS using cabal2nix. It wraps (and thus depends on) a foreign library which on Ubuntu one would build by `wget`ting the source, then running `make && make install && ldconfig`. Thus when cabal goes to build the program, it is apparently able to find the appropriate header files (which are in `/usr/local/include/ta-lib` or `/usr/include/ta-lib`).

On Nix, the process as I understand is to setup a .nix file to specify how to get and build the source, and then Nix sets up the isolated build environments. When I do this, the foreign library is fetched and built appropriately.

When Nix runs the configure step, it looks alright:

```
configureFlags: --verbose --prefix=/nix/store/fwpw03bd0c2m5yb7v2wc7g6f0qj912ra-talib-0.1.0.0 --libdir=$prefix/lib/$compiler --libsubdir=$pkgid --with-gcc=gcc --package-db=/tmp/nix-build-talib-0.1.0.0.drv-0/package.conf.d --ghc-option=-optl=-Wl,-rpath=/nix/store/fwpw03bd0c2m5yb7v2wc7g6f0qj912ra-talib-0.1.0.0/lib/ghc-7.10.2/talib-0.1.0.0 --enable-split-objs --disable-library-profiling --disable-executable-profiling --enable-shared --enable-library-vanilla --enable-executable-dynamic --enable-tests --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/gvglncjgd5yif9bc03qalmp2mrjp524n-ta-lib-0.4.0/include --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/gvglncjgd5yif9bc03qalmp2mrjp524n-ta-lib-0.4.0/lib
```

With `--extra-include-dirs` and `--extra-lib-dirs` set to the correct paths in the Nix store. However, when it goes to build it complains with,

```
Setup: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: ta_lib
```

Unfortunately I don't understand how cabal is determining whether the foreign library is present. I read here ([Haskell how to resolve cabal error: Missing dependencies on foreign libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303708/haskell-how-to-resolve-cabal-error-missing-dependencies-on-foreign-libraries)) that cabal will try to build and link a C program that consists of  for each header it finds. So, somehow it is not finding the correct library.

What is wrong? Does this have to do with the step in Ubuntu of running ldconfig?

Comment: What is `ta-lib`? I cannot find it in Nixpkgs.

Comment: you're right, it's not in nixpkgs. here's my ta_lib.nix file: https://gist.github.com/charles-cooper/0bd4398f223e64ba52f6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `ta_lib` depends on the system math library `m`, but that library isn't linked by default. You can check that by creating a stub C program

```
echo "int main() { return 0; }" >test.c
```

and trying to link that with `ta_lib`:

```
$ nix-shell -p ta_lib --run "gcc test.c -lta_lib"
/nix/store/ghinzmxfm2s41nz8y873jlywwmcbw38l-ta-lib-0.4.0/lib/libta_lib.so: undefined reference to `sinh'
/nix/store/ghinzmxfm2s41nz8y873jlywwmcbw38l-ta-lib-0.4.0/lib/libta_lib.so: undefined reference to `sincos'
[...]
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now, when Cabal tries to determine whether the library is available, it will attempt to link it to a stub test program, but that attempt will fail because of all those undefined symbol. Hence, Cabal complains that the library cannot be linked (even though its paths are configured and set-up correctly).

To remedy that issue, add the `m` library to the `extra-libraries` attribute in your project's Cabal file, like so:

```
extra-libraries: ta_lib, m
```

That should make the Cabal configure phase succeed.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I have got the same issue with `python, python2 or pepper`. Adding them to extra-libraries won't work while `tar, jq` do. Is this the same issue ? If so what is the workarond ? I have been trying the suggestion but without success.

Comment: I have the same issue but with pretty standard libraries like `libmnl` which is part of Nixpkgs. I run the same command `gcc test.c -lmnl` and it works, but Cabal can still not find the program.