# Finding foreign library with cabal using nix-shell

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix

I have a similar problem to: [Cabal can't find foreign library when building on NixOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34457141/582917)

Basically I'm using `cabal2nix` to generate from a package.yaml containing:

```
extra-libraries:
  - libmnl
```

This produces a cabal.nix file:

```
{ mkDerivation, base, bytestring, cereal, containers, hpack
, iproute, lens, libmnl, netlink, primitive
, resourcet, safe-exceptions, stdenv, transformers
}:
mkDerivation {
  pname = "relay";
  version = "0.1.0.0";
  src = ./.;
  libraryHaskellDepends = [
    base bytestring cereal containers iproute lens netlink
    primitive resourcet safe-exceptions transformers
  ];
  librarySystemDepends = [ libmnl ];
  libraryToolDepends = [ hpack ];
  testHaskellDepends = [
    base bytestring cereal containers iproute lens netlink
    primitive resourcet safe-exceptions transformers
  ];
  testSystemDepends = [ libmnl ];
  preConfigure = "hpack";
  homepage = "https://github.com/MatrixAI/Relay#readme";
  license = stdenv.lib.licenses.asl20;
}
```

If I enter into this via `nix-shell`, and run `cabal configure`. It complains that it cannot find libmnl:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring relay-0.1.0.0...
cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing (or bad) C library: libmnl
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.If the
library file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
```

Also running `gcc -c test.c -lmnl` on this file inside `nix-shell` works:

```
#include <libmnl/libmnl.h>

int main() { return 0; }
```

So why is cabal failing to find `libmnl` but `gcc` can easily find it in the `nix-shell`.

When running with `-v3` it appears to try to link to `-llibmnl`. But the proper linking should be `-lmnl`. This seems very problematic, is there a way to tell cabal to be linking with the flag `-lmnl`, not `-llibmnl`?

I've found that if I edit the Cabal file and change `extra-libraries` to point to `mnl` instead of `libmnl`, it then works by changing how Cabal tries to link. However the `cabal2nix` then when taking `package.yaml` generates `libmnl` which is the correct package attribute from Nix. It appears that `extra-libraries` should be `mnl` whereas the `cabal.nix` should be `libmnl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the the `extra-libraries` need to be using `mnl` not `libmnl`. Then when using `cabal2nix`, it needs to map `libmnl` package to the `mnl` attribute. This was solved with upstream cabal2nix mapping mnl to libmnl commit: https://github.com/NixOS/cabal2nix/issues/413#event-2257811946